# how to print polish characters in zebra printer in java?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, polish

I need to print a label with polish characters. When I use unicode UTF-16 this is ok.

```
^FO380,20^A0N,40,40^FD ZŁ^FS
```

This is ok, Polish characters is printed.

Well, when you use the function `^FB` Polish characters do not print in the printer:

```
^FO40,140,0^FB400,2,0,C^A0N,30,30^FH^FDłśąąśąąęććóó^FS
```

What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

The `^FB` command seems to have some limitations.

From page 187 of the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf):

> The `^FB` command does not support complex text. For complex text support, use `^TB`.

And on page 179:

> The Field Block (`^FB`) command cannot support the large TrueType fonts.

Have you tried using `^TB` instead?